# How to write back from top using PrintWriter in JAVA?

Tags: java, printwriter

Using PrintWriter to write to a txt file. But now I have a problem: Can I write from the top line after I write some lines? For example, I have write:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("result.txt");
out.print("first line");
out.print("second line");
```

Then, can I write back from the first line? So I can write the String top = "top line" before the first line like the following:

```
top line
first line
second line
```

The problem is, I can get the content of String top only after I write "top line" and "second line". How can I write to the beginning of the file?

Thank you!

Comment: Change the logic of your program. Compute the top line, then write it. I don't see why you would only be able to compute the first line after the two following ones are written. If you can't handle it, post the relevant part of your code.

Comment: Well, in fact, I need to do search algorithm to find the path from start point to end point. But the result.txt requires I should first show the path then should show the process of how I find the path. So is impossible I can show the final result before I found it.

Comment: Put it in a StringBuilder first, then write the path, then the StringBuilder contents.

Comment: So, compute the path in memory, and when you have it, write it. Why do you want to write anything from the start. See it as a computer and a printer. The computer is the memory. The printer is your PrintWriter. When you write a document, you write everything on the computer, and only when the document is ready to be printed, you send it to the printer.

Comment: Yes I agree with your idea, compute the path but not print it before I find the final path. Then I print the path, then the process to find the path. But could you be more specified what class should I use? StringBuilder to hold the process? But it seems a little complex. Other good idea? Sorry I don't know the library very well. I only used PrintWriter before...

Comment: No idea. I don't even know what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: Better than a StringBuilder: a List< Edge >, you add edges as you discover them then reorder (sort or reverse) then print the list.

Comment: Is the List<Edge> a class? Could you show me the reference about how to user it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to implement this, would simply be to read in the entire file as a string, append your pre-fix line onto the start of it, and overwrite the contents of the file with the String's content using a PrintWriter object. It's not exactly what you wanted, but it has the exact same effect. :)

Comment: Remember to mark the most useful answer as the correct one, for future readers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class and its [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method, but write on top doesn't insert lines but overwrites them. It's not that you want. I agree with [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) comment, the best is to compute first, then write.

If you known the size of the first line you have to write 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' to fill it and after writing the others lines, back to the top and replace it by the good one with the same count of characters. Possible but not recommended.

Comment: Sorry I can not know the size of first lines. You can find my problem from my reply to JB Nizet. It seems not so easy...